# jQuery post dialog close

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a dialog which have two buttons: "Yes" and "No".
For the "Yes", I will do some database operation via

```
$.ajax({
    type: post
    ...
})
```

under the Success section, I need to redirect part of my html tag with a new page, which works fine. And after that I wish to close the dialog, which doesn't work.

The cmd I use is

```
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

and

```
$(this).parents(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close');
```

None of above works inside my Success section. I think it may due to the redirection. Not sure yet.

Does any one have some idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you include more of the code? The entire function to handle clicking on "Yes" would be fantastic - inside the `success` callback handler of your AJAX call `this` isn't what you think it is/need it to be.

Comment: I have solved the problem by cernunnos's idea. Thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using $(this) inside the success function, if this is true then your problem is that "this" no longer points to your dialog.

Save the reference to the dialog div before you call the ajax function then use this reference inside the success function

```
// before ajax
var that = this

// inside success
$(that).dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give an id to your dialog and in your ajax success callback put:

```
$( "#yourDialogId" ).dialog( "close" );
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Actually, you solution works and easier. However, cernunnos gave the underlying reason why my way doesn't work.